# ostream read/write functions

Tags: c++, file-io, ostream

I have the following function:

```
void IBinary::writeb( std::ostream& out, double x )
{
   out.write( (char*)&(x), sizeof(double) );
}
```

This takes the address of `x` and casts it to a pointer of type `char*`. I do not understand how/why the first argument to `write` is of type `char*`, even if I'm writing a `double` to a file. There are several overloads of the `writeb` function and all of them cast to a `char*`.

Wouldn't that be the equivalent of:

```
double x = 3.14;
char* c;
c = (char*)&(x);    // ah!
```

My guess is that this works because we are also passing the size of `double` to `ostream::write`. On my computer the size of `char` is 1 byte, but that isn't always going to be true.

Thus, why does the first argument of `ostream::write` expect a `char*` no matter what type of variable is being written?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Nitpick/FYI: `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte by definition.  That "byte" as the compiler sees it might not be exactly 8 bits depending on your system.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a pointer to `char`, not just a `char`. The pointer `c`  points at the first byte of the object in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look up the documentation for [write](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)?

> basic_ostream& write( const char_type* s, std::streamsize count );

The first parameter is `const char_type* s`, which means for a `std::ostream` you need to pass a type `const char*` or `char*`. `write` does not accept any other types.

Now, personally I would write `(char*)&(x)` as `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x)`, but leaving that aside, first you take the address of the object using the `&` (the address-of operator). Next you cast it to a `char*`. Since a `char` is one byte, it writes one byte of the object at a time the number of characters specified in `count`. The cast is there so that the object can be passed to `write` and so it can spit out the binary representation of the object since you are writing one byte at a time. The `char*` would point to the first byte of the object and `write` knows how many bytes big the object is based on you passing `sizeof(double)` as the second argument.

Note that this is a simple form of serialization.

> On my computer the size of char is 1 byte, but that isn't always going
>   to be true.

That is incorrect. `char` is guaranteed to always be one byte.

Comment: I agree that the function should be updated to use C++ style casts. I saw mixed answers about `sizeof(char)` being 1. With that in mind, we are simply using `char` to write out whichever type byte by byte?

Comment: @Derek: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`ostream::write` is an [unformatted output function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).  **Unformatted** in this case means it's blindly writing out whatever bytes you give it.  Using a `char *` is the best (only?) way to do that.